# vscode import of android.util.Log is overwritten to sun.rmi.runtime.Log;

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am having a strange problem with vscode in a little two file Java project.

Every time I save my file, the import of `android.util.Log` is overwritten to `sun.rmi.runtime.Log;` producing build errors and it is driving me crazy.

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use the Java Extension Pack.

Just add this to your vscode settings.json:

> "java.saveActions.organizeImports": false

This is a work around and not a fix for the auto import priority.

Comment: This helped me. I had to also disable `organizeImports` in vscode globally.